# Android Timer thread which exits on a "is true" condition

Tags: android, timer, boolean

I'm writing an Android application and I need a Timer to be set which will execute a method every one second and then stop once a boolean variable (set by aforementioned method) becomes true.

Here's an overview of what I'm trying to do:

```
boolean done = false;    

public void someMethod() {
    if(done == false) {
       myTimer = new Timer(); //Set up a timer, to execute TimerMethod repeatedly
       myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               TimerMethod();
            }
        }, 0, 1000);
    }

    if(done == true) { 
        //TimerMethod will eventually set 'done' to true. When this happen, do layout modifying stuff here. Causes error as non-UI thread is executing the layout modifying stuff. Do I spawn a new UI thread here to do it? If so, how? :/
    }
}

TimerMethod() {
   String result = someServerMethod();
   if(result == "theResultWeWant") {
         myTimer.cancel(); //stop the timer - we're done!
         done = true; //set 'done' to true so the line of code in someMethod() will now run
         someMethod();
   }
}
```

Edit: I've updated the code above to reflect what I'd like to do. I'm hoping I can get the done flash to be set to true and then carry on executing someMethod but I'm sure it's not that simple! Do I perhaps need to spawn a new thread from TimerMethod() to execute the code from the `done == true` line?

Comment: Is your problem that it is never going into the stop condition or that you don't know what code to use to stop? If the latter, myTimer.cancel() will do the trick.

Comment: cancel() is definetly what I'll be using. I've got the timer to now go and query my server and get the result, and to cancel the timer after this has been done. Now I need it to carry on executing the rest of the code in someMethod()....

Comment: why not start your method from within the if clause? if (result) { myTimer.cancel(); doSecondMethod()}...additionally, you could structure it so it's executed in someMethod() by changing if (done == true) to while(!done); doSecondMethod(), but this will block your UI thread (bad).

Comment: I've tried to put the doSecondMethod into the done==true if clause, but it doesn't seem to run. It seems TimerMethod() is getting run fine until it's cancelled, but then someMethod() doesn't carry on where it left off. I've also tried calling someMethod() from the TimerMethod() after myTimer.cancel() but Logcat reports a problem as a non-UI thread is trying to modify the layout (which is what I want to happen if done==true)..

Comment: someMethod doesn't want for done == true. It starts the timer, checks to see if done == true (which it's not), and then finishes. You need to either post a runnable on the UI thread or use a handler to execute your UI method, i'll post an answer to give you an idea of what to do.

Comment: please help me too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50116313/inactive-webview-for-24-hours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All UI interactions need to be done from the main(UI) thread. In your case, you were calling someMethod() from your TimerTask which is a seperate thread. A handler is used to interact with your main thread from a helper thread.

```
    public void someMethod() {

          myTimer = new Timer(); //Set up a timer, to execute TimerMethod repeatedly
          myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                  TimerMethod();
               }
           }, 0, 1000);
       }

    }

    TimerMethod() {
       String result = someServerMethod();
       if(result.equals("theResultWeWant")) {
             myTimer.cancel(); //stop the timer - we're done!
             mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0): //send message to handler to update UI
       }
    }

private Handler mHandler = new Handler(){
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        doUIMethod();
    }

};
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Joe, have got it sorted now - your answer was very helpful!